# Button value and text

Tags: html, css, button

Is there anyway I can add text and show the value in the button tag (i need the '+ |' to be a font)?

something like:

```
<button type="submit" value="add to friends list">+ |</button>
```

This doesn't work, any suggestions? I've created a fiddle with what it needs to look like:

http://jsfiddle.net/bAv7C/

Thanks.

== update ==

Working now, here's the new fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/bAv7C/4/

Thanks all

Comment: the value of a button is what will be passed in the request headers to the next script when submitted. What you wan the text on the button to be goes in the tag. I suspect you want the value of teh button to be adFriend and the '+ |' to be '+ | add to friends list'

Comment: You c'ant do this way...........!

Comment: why are you not adding this inside value itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need it to be a button, this should be fine, and validates in HTML5:

```
<button type="submit" value="add">+ | Add to friends list</button>
```

The value is for form purposes.

Comment: Yep, cheers for the suggestion. It's me being slow this morning! I forgot that i can place a span between the '+ |" and float it left. Thanks.

Comment: *span around (not between).

Comment: No problem, it is Friday after all! :)

Comment: :) Only a few hours to go till beer o'clock!

Answer (score 1):

Follow on from my commont to OP...

What I suspect you want is:

```
<button type="submit" value="addFriend">+ |</button>
```

BUT if you want to use values of attributes in the content of an element:

CSS:

```
button:after
{
    content: " " attr(value);
}
```

Markup:

```
<button type="submit" value="add to friends list">+ |</button>
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bAv7C/5/)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<input type="submit" value="+ | add to friends list" />
```

Anyway, I would recommend you to use image of `+` or any other way than text.

Comment: Hi, it has to be text as it's populated from a stored font for high resolution. With regards to your suggestion I would need to center the 'atfl' and left align the '+ |', which can't be dont.

Comment: I don't understand where the problem is. The value of a button is displayed as a text and you can change its font. And as I wrote, it's pretty weird to use text `+ |` instead of some image on background of the button.

Comment: Welcome to the world of work :/ (thanks for your suggestion).

Answer (score 0):

i did not understand are you trying something this.

```
 <button type="submit" value="add to friends list">+ | add to friends list</button>
```